# Google Colab A100 slower than CPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I tried to implement a neural network using TensorFlow Keras on a classification dataset from Kaggle. I believe I've implemented it correctly. However, I've noticed that it is faster to train (true when doing CV for parameter tuning) when I am on Google Colab's CPU than Google Colab's A100 (Colab Pro+).

Any thoughts to why that may be? I'd tried increasing the complexity of the hyperparameters (i.e. more hidden layers), but CPU is still faster than the GPU.

URL to data: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nelgiriyewithana/apple-quality/data

Code:

```py
# Data manipulation libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Machine learning libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, learning_curve
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

# Plotting libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# To measure time
import time

# Set seed
SEED = 42

#Check the version of TensorFlow you are using
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))

# Now use pandas to read the csv file
df = pd.read_csv('apple_quality.csv')

# Drop the last row
df = df.drop(df.index[-1])

# Let's see the first few rows of the dataset
print(df.head())

# Process data and split into training set and test set
# Let's assume that your target variable is 'Quality' and rest are features (except A_id)
features = df.drop(['A_id', 'Quality'], axis=1)
target = df['Quality']

# Encode 'Quality' to numerical values
target = target.map({'good': 1, 'bad': 0})

# Split the dataset into training set and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.2, random_state=SEED)

# Convert all X to float
X_train, X_test = X_train.astype(float), X_test.astype(float)

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,), activation='relu', alpha=0.0001):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(hidden_layer_sizes[0], input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation=activation))

    for layer_size in hidden_layer_sizes[1:]:
        model.add(Dense(layer_size, activation=activation))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

# Create a KerasClassifier
keras_clf = KerasClassifier(model=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=10, random_state=SEED, verbose=0)

# Fit the model to the training data
keras_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict on the test data
predictions = keras_clf.predict(X_test)

# Calculate the accuracy of the predictions
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)

print(f'Accuracy of Neural Network without hyperparameter tuning is {acc*100:.2f}%')

# Define the grid search parameters
param_grid = {
    'model__hidden_layer_sizes': [(10,), (20,), (10, 10), (20, 20)],
    'model__alpha': [0.0001, 0.01, 0.1],
}

# Create Grid Search
start = time.time()
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=keras_clf, param_grid=param_grid, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
end = time.time()
print(f'Grid Search time: {end - start}')

# Print the best parameters
print("Best parameters found: ", grid_result.best_params_)

# Calculate the accuracy with the best parameters
best_predictions = grid_result.predict(X_test)
best_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, best_predictions)

print(f'Accuracy of Neural Network after hyperparameter tuning is {best_acc*100:.2f}%')
```